# can i convert ArrayBuffer to string?

Tags: html, uploading

I am working on html5 uploading script.
I want md5 hash for every chunk of file stream.

here is I am using FileReader for reading stream but when I pass reader result to base64 class
I got exception.
Object doesn't support property or method 'charCodeAt'

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (f) {
var hash = MD5(Base64.encode(f.target.result));
                };
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the job:

replace

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

With

```
reader.readAsText(blob);
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsText

Answer (score 0):

You should have to try this way:-

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));` runs the risk of an error with large strings, because you're actually calling fromCharCode with a number of arguments equal to the length of your string.  The 'apply' call expands to  something like: `String.fromCharCode(buf[0],buf[1],buf[2],...,buf[buf.length]);` which will crash if buf is too long.  It's concise, but the calling convention is rather obnoxious, and this is better handled with a concatination loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Base64 is unnecessary.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    var hash = MD5(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(blob,'iso-8859-1');
```