# How can I write a file in ISO-8859-1 with Chrome's File API

Tags: javascript, ruby, character-encoding, w3c, html5-filesystem

At the moment I am writing a file like this:

```
var blob = new Blob([contents], {type: 'text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1'});
fileWriter.write(blob);
```

However, when I run `file -i` on the resulting file the charset is always UTF-8.

The variable `contents` is encoded in ISO-8859-1 on the server side, and then communicated over the wire in base64:

```
def write_csv_file
  filewriter = RMS::LabelFile.for_order(self.order)
  csv = filewriter.to_csv
  csv = csv.encode("ISO-8859-1")
  csv = Base64.encode64(csv)
  %Q{<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1">
        var csv_data = #{csv.inspect.gsub('\n', '')};
        csv_data = window.atob(csv_data);
        parent.phn.filewriter.writeFile("#{self.order.order_number}.csv", csv_data, 'ISO-8859-1');
      </script>
  }
end
```

I've checked and double checked that the encoding is still ISO-8859-1 on the client side in the javascript. It seems like Blob and fileWriter are changing the encoding before they write. Examining the [W3C's working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#constructorBlob) it seems as though Blob converts DOMStrings to UTF-8 before writing them.

Comment: `file -i` is just guessing. If there's no latin1 chars it won't guess latin1

Comment: There are latin chars. Yeah I noticed that right away, so I started to view the files in my browser with different encodings. The data is definitely being re-encoded in UTF-8 at some point (presumably by the BLOB).

Comment: possible duplicate of [can i convert ArrayBuffer to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031433/can-i-convert-arraybuffer-to-string)